# JSONException : java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Tags: android, json, listview

Im trying to show the subject taken per student in listview once he/she login. I bring the user from the login page using shared preferences. Did it error on JSONParser ?

The logcat error.

```
   03-30 18:02:26.457: I/System.out(28204): Response : User Found
   03-30 18:02:26.715: D/Response:(28204): 123{"success":1,"student":   [{"matrix_id":"123","ic_no":"123","name":"ALI","email":"ALI@yahoo.com"}]}
   03-30 18:02:26.723: W/System.err(28204): org.json.JSONException: Value 123 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject
   03-30 18:02:26.731: W/System.err(28204):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
   03-30 18:02:26.731: W/System.err(28204):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
   03-30 18:02:26.731: W/System.err(28204):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
   03-30 18:02:26.731: W/System.err(28204):     at com.ultra.esc.ScheduleFragment$LoadAllSubject.doInBackground(ScheduleFragment.java:146)
   03-30 18:02:26.731: W/System.err(28204):     at com.ultra.esc.ScheduleFragment$LoadAllSubject.doInBackground(ScheduleFragment.java:1)
   03-30 18:02:26.731: W/System.err(28204):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
  03-30 18:02:26.731: W/System.err(28204):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
  03-30 18:02:26.731: W/System.err(28204):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
  03-30 18:02:26.731: W/System.err(28204):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
  03-30 18:02:26.731: W/System.err(28204):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
 03-30 18:02:26.731: W/System.err(28204):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This is code after login.

```
   //Bring the value from login page----------------------------------------------
   SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   matrix_id = settings.getString("matrix","");

   TextView matrix = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textMatrix);      
   matrix.setText(settings.getString("matrix", "XXXXX"));
```

Pass the value to JSON code.

```
  //protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // post matrix_id as GET parameters
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("matrix_id", matrix_id));

        // getting JSON string from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_subjects, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Response: ", json);          

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json); 

            if(jObj != null){
                String matrix_id = jObj.getString(TAG_MATRIX_ID);
                subject = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (subject != null) {
                // looping through All Subjects
                for (int i = 0; i < subject.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = subject.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String subject = c.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("matrix_id", matrix_id);
                    map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    subjectList.add(map);
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {   Log.d("Subjects: ", "null");}

        }
         catch (JSONException e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

   protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        super.onPostExecute(file_url);
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread           
                 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                           getActivity(), subjectList,
                        R.layout.all_subject, new String[] {TAG_MATRIX_ID,TAG_SUBJECT},
                        new int[] { R.id.matrix_id, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: please post all logcat error, yes it is while parsing

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I have post the logcat error

Comment: `123{"success":1,"student":   [{"matrix_id":"123","ic_no":"123","name":"ALI","email":"ALI@yahoo.com"}]}` : is the initial **123** (before the "{" ) a part of your response as well.. ?

Comment: @Swayam Actually I want to check whether the value that bring from the login is correct or not, so I call the matrix. Yes it response.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you are saying that even the initial 123 is a part of your response? But, then the JSON format is not valid. I mean, you cant start a JSON response like this directly.

Comment: @Swayam check my post, part the code after login, this is where the matrix_id="123" is exist, it comes from the login. After that I pass the variable of matrix_id to the params.

Comment: Yes, that part is correct. But in your Log, the response starts with 123 directly, even before the braces.

Comment: @Swayam Actually I echo that on my PHP, What's your suggest sir ?

Comment: Yeah..you are echoing that and it is becoming a part of your response that Android receives. SO, you need to make sure first whether the JSON you are sending is in the correct format or not. Try http://json.parser.online.fr/ to ensure it's correct.

Comment: @Swayam `SyntaxError: Unexpected token p` what does that mean ?

Comment: Well, like I told you earlier. there must be something wrong in the JSON data that the server is sending to you. Could you please mention the final response that you are getting?

Comment: @Swayam Can I add you at facebook ?

Comment: Uhh..well..okay. Cool.

Comment: @Swayam sir did u online ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you are getting an array as an object. Try this:

```
SomeStudentModel model;
ArrayList<SomeStudentModel> typeList = new ArrayList<>();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();

JSONObject jsonobject;

 try {

      JSONArray result = response.getJSONArray("student");
          for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
             jsonobject = result.getJSONObject(i);
             brand = gson.fromJson(jsonobject.toString(),
             SomeStudentModel.class);
             typeList.add(brand);
          }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think it'd be a good idea to post the entire logcat error as @shayan pourvatan said.

Judging from that 1 line you pasted into your post, I'd think there's some kind of problem when converting an `Integer` object into `JSONObject`. What I'd suggest is instead of putting the `Integer` into your json, convert it to `String` first and see if that helps (i.e. `Integer.toString(/*your number here*/)`.